# Finding the domain of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find the domain of  convergence

$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (z-1)^n$

My attempt : $-1 < (z-1) <1 \tag 1$

adding $1$ on  $(1)$, we have

$0 \le z <2$

so the domain convergence will be $z \in [0,2)$

Is its true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is really a quastion about Complex Analysis, then your answer doesn't makes sense. Since $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]n=1$, the radius of convergence is $1$. And, if $|z-1|=1$, then you don't have $\lim_nn|z-1|=0$, and therefore the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(z-1)^n$ diverges So, your series converges if and only if $|z-1|<1$.

Comment: yes sir, its about complex analysis @Jose carlos

Comment: Im confused $|z-1| <1 $or $|z-i|< 1$  which one is true @Jose carlos sir

Comment: THe series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(z-1)^n$. So, yes, I meant $z-1$. Why should it be $z-i$?

Comment: okss  Got it  Now  thanks u  sir  @Jose carlos

Answer (score 1):

The series is divergent for $z=0$ as well as $z=2$. So the domain is $(0,2)$.

Comment: Kavi sir  at $z=0$ ,i think  it is convergent by leibtnitz test

Comment: @jasmine Your question is about $\sum n(z-1)^{n}$. You can apply Leibniz test if you have $\sum (z-1)^{n} /n$.

Comment: ohh Got it , thanks u kavi sir